# Responsive page size ignoring viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, viewport

Im doing the responsive part of a website but I am not beeing able to define the page size, I have 98% but the page continues to the right side of the screen (we can scroll to the side) and I don't want that. This is the page I am working on: [Webpage BarberShop](http://www.style-euclides.pt)

How do I define the page, to never ignore viewport size?

**HTML**

```
<div id="home"> ... content ... </div>
<div id="services"> ... content ... </div>
<div id="team"> ... content ... </div>
<div id="contact"> ... content ... </div>
```

**CSS Media Queries**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width:320px){

    html, body{background-color: #27ae60; width: device-width; zoom: 1.0; display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
    #home, #services, #team, #space #contact{width: 98%;}
    .container{width: 96%; margin: 0 2%;}
    #nav, #home .social, #slider, .premio, #contact #map, #gallery, #space, #footer p#by, #footer a, #contact label {display: none !important;}
    .spacer{width: 100%; height: 50px;}
    nav{display: block; z-index: 5; position: fixed;}
    #home .holder .block, #team .holder .block{display: block; width: 95%;}
    #welcome {margin: 0; margin: 605x auto 25px auto !important;}
    #home #welcome img {display: block; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 2px; width: 250px; height: auto;}
    #home .holder .block p{margin-bottom: 12px !important;}
    #service .top-area{margin: 0 auto !important; margin: 2px 0 2px 0 !important;}
    #footer p#by{display: none;} #footer .holder p{font-size:0.855em !important; display: inline-block;}
    nav span{display: inline; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; line-height: 50px; margin-left: 0.5%; margin-right: 0.1%; font-weight: bold;}
    #contact #local{width: 90% !important;} #contact #define{margin-right: 2px !important; margin-left: 2px !important; padding: 4px !important;}
}
```

Comment: `width: device-width;` is invalid CSS.

Comment: You should take a look at what other responsive layouts do, like this: http://www.getskeleton.com/

Comment: i didn't knew that was invalid. What should I do then?